# input.focus() not opening keyboard in iOS Device

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, focus

input.focus() not opening keyboard in iOS Device 
I am using below code
inputchatvar.focus();
through debugger i found we are getting focus on this element as well but iOS Device not opening the keyboard or autofocus the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
   inputchatvar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: I am not using webView ,It is an web chat  application (html,css,javascript) so this function will not work on this